# Backstage deployment on kubernetes

Tags: backstage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLS6b.jpg)Can anyone tell how to deploy backstage on kubernetes.
I am following the steps exactly in doc
But here in the yarn commands i amm getting errors , even though I am able to see yarn version, i am unable to run getting tdc command not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xfz9.jpg)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Or paste the errors as well

Comment: Added now in the question can you please check it

Comment: Try to follow this guide, wrote it a few days ago and it works for me. https://www.mrnice.dev/posts/how-to-backstage-part-1/

Comment: @saikrishna can you provide more info, I've recently deployed this into kubernetes.